# How to find the optimal n cloumn vectors for minimum combination from 1000 vectors

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The origianl data is about 1000 column vectors, my purpose is: firstly, choose n of them. secondly, generate the minimum vector of the n vectors and calculate the summary of the minimum vector. thirdly, I use the itertools to genertate the whole combinations of n in 1000 vectors. finally, after comparing all the summaries, the optimal n vectors are determined.

The question is: when n=1 or n=2, the calculation time is acceptable, using 0.3 and 18 seconds respeictively. but when n>=3, the calculation time rise exponentially, and all spent on the combinations. Is there any other suitable solutions?

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
n = 2                                       # the chosen number of vectors
dic = np.load("data.npy",allow_pickle=True) # import the 1000 vetors, they are saved as dictionary
Summary = []
Index = []
for c in combinations(dic.keys(), n):
    minvector = np.minimum(dic[c[0]] , dic[c[1]]) # two vectors because n=2, equals to n
    Summary.append(np.sum(minvector))
    Index.append(c)
    # print(c)
print(Index[np.argmin(Summary)])
```

| Vector1 | Vector2 | ... | Vector999 | Vector1000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 5 | ... | 7 | 10 |
| 9 | 2 | ... | 3 | 9 |
| 5 | 1 | ... | 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 9 | ... | 6 | 3 |
| 3 | 9 | ... | 8 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | ... | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 8 | ... | 5 | 8 |

Taking these vectors as example, if I choose vector1 and vector2, the minimum vector will be [5,2,1,4,3,3,6] and the summary will be 24. if I choose vector2 and vector999, the minimum vector will be [5,2,1,6,8,3,5] and the summary will be 30. After calculating all the combinations, I can get the optimal 2 vectors. However, when n=3, the question will consume a lot of time.

Comment: How  many combinations are there for 1000 items taken 3 at a time?

Comment: Choose 3 from 1000 will be C(1000,3)=166167000 combinations, so I can't use the enumeration method @hpaulj